# Spring STS 3.9.7 skips install process and opens workspace

Tags: spring

I am following online tutorials on the basics of Java which recommend using spring sts as a workspace.  I have also watched multiple installation videos where the presenter downloads Spring STS, walks through the installation process, and sets the JVM path during the  installation wizard.

My issue is that after downloading Spring STS 3.9.7, I do not see any file that appears to be the installer.  Among my downloaded files is eclipse.exe and STS.exe.  When I run STS.exe, it loads the Spring workspace, an skips over the setup/installation wizard, where I would also set the JDK path. It does not seem to install STS, as I do not see any shortcuts in my start menu.

I have JDK 1.8.0_151 installed on Windows 7. I did have to shorten my folder path for STS in order to avoid unzip errors.  I am using whatever extractor defaults with for my OS. I have downloaded this same file from the Spring.io site multiple times to see if it was an issue with the download process.

Where did I go wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Setting The JDK](https://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v397/NewAndNoteworthy.html) section here.  They suggest modifying `sts.ini` to setup the JDK.

Comment: Thank you Tom!  I set the JDK as an argument in the sts.ini as stated in the page you referenced.  While that did not solve my specific installation issue, it did allow me to compile and run a java application.  I appreciate your response.

Comment: Hey! So glad that that is what worked out! I updated this with an answer so that future readers will find the information more readily.  If you think it fixes your issue feel free to accept it.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: My actual issue is that while I can run the sts.exe and open STS Spring, it is not performing a full install with start menu or desktop shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `sts.ini` file to setup the JDK.  See the documentation under [Setting the JDK](https://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v397/NewAndNoteworthy.html).

`Add a line at the beginning "-vm" and an additional line below that which points to the "javaw" executable of the JDK on your machine.`

Here is a more in-depth [documentation for configuring the JVM](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)